# Write data from Derby to JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, derby, javadb

I'm new to JavaDb/Derby.I'm migrating a project from MySQL to Derby (Project made with JavaFX).I have created an Embedded Db under NetBeans. GUI has Serial Number field (textfield), Name field (textfield), ImageView and TableView (columns with respective data). Below is the java code for connecting with Derby.

```
    public static Connection ConnectionDb() {
    try{
    String url = "jdbc:derby:Test_JavaDb/webdb;create=true";   

    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    if (conn != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected to database #1");
    }
    return  conn;

    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    return null;
   }

//BELOW METHOD IS LINKED TO A BUTTON FOR LOADING TABLE   
  @FXML public void LoadTable(){
  data.clear();
  try{
  conn = lrconn.ConnectionDb();
  String sql = "select * from TEST";
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
  data.add(new TestPOJO(
  rs.getString(1),
  rs.getString(2),
  rs.getString(3)));               
  Table.setItems(data);                    
  }
  pst.close();
  rs.close();   
  }catch(Exception e1){
  }

  Table.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent me) -> {  
  try {            
  conn = lrconn.ConnectionDb();
  TestPOJO user = (TestPOJO) Table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
  String sql = "select * from TEST where SLNO =?";  
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pst.setString(1, user.getSLNO());
  rs = pst.executeQuery();

  while (rs.next()) {
  slnoField.setText(rs.getString(1));
  nameField.setText(rs.getString(2));

  try (InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(3)) {
  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("photo1.jpg"));
  byte[] content = new byte[1024];
  int size = 0;
  while((size= is.read(content))!=-1){
  os.write(content,0,size);
  }
  os.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  image1 = new Image("file:photo1.jpg");
  imgvw.setImage(image1);

  rs.close();
  pst.close();
  }catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }  
  });

  Table.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent e) -> {
  if(e.getCode()== KeyCode.UP || e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN){
  try {
  TestPOJO user = (TestPOJO) Table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
  String sql = "select * from TEST where SLNO =?";
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pst.setString(1, user.getSLNO());
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {
  slnoField.setText(rs.getString(1));
  nameField.setText(rs.getString(2));

  try (InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(3)) {
  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("photo1.jpg"));
  byte[] content = new byte[1024];
  int size = 0;
  while((size= is.read(content))!=-1){
  os.write(content,0,size);
  }os.close();
  }

  image1 = new Image("file:photo1.jpg");
  imgvw.setImage(image1);
  }}catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  }
  });
  }
```

The connection works as I get the output "Connected to database #1" on executing code (Clicking on LOAD TABLE BUTTON). But GUI table does not get updated with data from the Embedded Database. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked in your log file to see if you get any exceptions?

Comment: Yes I have, there aren't any exceptions to work with.

Comment: Perhaps you should step through your code with a debugger, and see if you can narrow down your question more precisely. Another possibility would be to run Derby with `derby.language.logStatementText=true` and then look in your derby.log, to see if seeing what SQL statement you're executing gives you some more clues about where your program goes astray.

Comment: Hi Bryan as a beginner I'm trying to get my feet into Derby system information as you've suggested going through this [http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/tadminconfigsysteminformation.html] as per your recommendation in a different forum.Could you also point me to any reference material/a complete tutorial that shows integration of JavaFX with DerbyDb. Thanks